# Why the following expression is a bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

$v\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mid{v}\mid = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$

The question, is the following a bilinear form, if yes than what matrix corresponds to it?$f(v,u)=\mid{v+u}\mid^2 - \mid{v}\mid^2 - \mid{u}\mid^2$

**Edit:**
I got the help and got 2 downvotes, should I delete the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the components of both vectors and you will find out.

Comment: Thank you! $f(v,u)= 2 \mid{u}\mid\mid{v}\mid cos(u,v) = 2\langle u,v \rangle$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct purpose of f.